# Regular Expression for Dreamweaver "Find/Replace" needed

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dreamweaver

I have some id tags which I need to remove completely, including its value.

Is this possible with an easy find/replace? Or some other fast method?

```
  <option name="blabla" id="29482" value="blabla">
```

I want the above to become:

```
  option name="blabla" value="blabla">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find

```
id="[^"]*["]
```

Replace with

```
etc
```

Tick on Use regular expression

[Info](http://somerandomdude.com/articles/technology/dreamweaver-regular-expressions/)

Answer (score 0):

You can download emeditor trial(http://www.emeditor.com/modules/download2/), its find/replace support regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifically looking for OPTION tags with ID attributes that you need to remove, Dreamweaver also offers the option for searching by tag name and removing attributes.

CTRL+F to open the Find dialog
In the Search list, select "Specific tag", select or enter "option" in list that appears to the right.
For this case you can probably leave the default of "Inside tag" "body" on the list immediately below the Search list, otherwise select "Inside tag" and "body".
In the "Action" list, select "Remove attribute", then enter or select "id" in the list that appears to the right.